# Short and Open Circuit Calculation

Tags: voltage, current, resistance, short-circuit, ohms-law

Suppose there is a ideal voltage source which can provide infinite power if that is needed in an ideal scenario. Now suppose a resister R is connected across it and the e.m.f is E. So by ohm's law the entire E will fall across R, despite of whatever the value of R is; except for 2 conditions,

1. If R=0, I=E/0=infinity. So E=IR=infinity*0=0, But if the supply gives E volts out and if the charges dissipates it's Total energy by end of the 0 ohm resistance and with the help of infinite current, then how the voltage across it can be 0 and not E?
2. If R=infinite, I=E/infinite=0. So, E=IR=0*infinite=0. Again the same thing. How can E be zero when at first E was not zero when supplied?

I know in real world nothing is ideal but here I'm  taking an ideal case for calculations. And I also know in case 2 if R=infinite or opened the voltage across it will be E but why the equation is not supporting that? And I'm not sure what will be the voltage in case 1. Is there any asymptote in the E vs R graph which is causing those behaviour in two cases?

Comment: If you want pure mathematics - then you should take in account "infinities" of different orders (or work with \$lim\$ notation and the involved calculus). Anyway, engineering models do not deal with the extreme cases and call such a cases "non-physical".

Comment: I know but can u say why this is happening? and also what do u mean by infinities of different orders?

Comment: Infinity can be of different "size". This is a whole field of mathematics and off-topic here. One thing you should understand - "infinity" is not a number and does not obey the regular arithmetic rules. Again, your calculations might make more sense if you rewrite them in the \$lim\$ notation.

Comment: For example, you say *infinity*0=0* - which is not necessarily true. Think of \$a=x\$ and \$b=\frac{1}{x^2}\$. Now, if \$x=0\$ then \$a=0\$ and \$b=\infty\$. Right? But what about \$ab\$? Obviously it is \$\frac{1}{x}=\infty\$. So here we get \$\infty\cdot 0 = \infty\$

Comment: Yea its a strange behaviour. need to search more on that topic.

Comment: The "behavior" you mention is mathematically pathological. The branch constituent equations we have are (imprecise) models for real-world impedances that we encounter; you mention a pathological condition that can't even arise with ideal superconductors in practice (since even a type-1 Sc has impedance in the form of series L).

Comment: I know that's why I told it's only in ideal case not real...only for calculations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different and opposing voltage sources?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/195354/different-and-opposing-voltage-sources)

Comment: This question is like asking what happens when an irresistable force is applied to an immovable object. The answer is you've created a logical contradiction. To call one object an irresistable force you must first know that no immovable object exists, and vice versa.

Comment: You can connect an ideal short circuit in parallel with an ideal, non-zero voltage source...that is an invalid circuit because you have violated the definition of parallel elements. And multiplying infinity times zero is equally nonsensical. GIGO

Answer (score 1):

Let's try a practical case.

Given a strong 18650 fully charged battery, Li Ion Cell ESR ~ 0.05 ohm  3.7V

If you had AWG 30 magnet wire coiled up to make a little solenoid and somehow it shorted inside, what would be the resistance , R be to make the hottest wire?

Please Cut wire < 1 second, otherwise ...V^2/0.05=273 Watts is explosive. self-heating energy that demands a safety fuse.

> What is the short circuit current?
>
> How long would you have before the battery melts down into a fire or explosive hazard?

Don't even joke about it.

Comment: Yea, in practical case it's not hard at all to determine what will happen